# Unable to access Web Service sometimes

Tags: java, web-services

I have been receiving this exception `from time to time`, `while accessing the webservice` `provided by this site.`

`webservice:` https://int.yumzing.com/index.php?func=sessionCreate.

It works for sometimes and then it doesn’t.
I have tried pinging the site `“int.yumzing.com”` , this works.... 
but `more frequently its inaccessible when i am trying to access the web service` through my program, passing the username and password.

`If there was some problem with my program, then it wouldnt had been accessible even for` `once... but it works from time to time.`

I am at present struck into this, as i cant understand that what can be the root of the problem.

Please see the Exception below, `What i know is that UnknownHostException will take place when there is a problem in the Intial Connection.`

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: int.yumzing.com
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.yum.zing.APIHandling$1.run(APIHandling.java:415)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: whats you IDE ? and server is it tomacat

Comment: I am using Eclipse. But i am not sure abt the server that whether its tomcat or not

Answer (score 1):

Any hostname, in your case `int.yumzing.com` is mapped somewhere on a machine to an IP. This is useful for example when you have a dynamic IP which changes often, because it allows transparent communications between the clients and the server. Otherwise all the clients should be made aware each time the IP address changes.

When someone is trying to access a server by its domain name, a cascade DNS call is initiated in order to find the IP of the target machine and establish a connection. For some internet related reason, mostly probably on your side, the resolution process fails and you get the error above.

For more info on DNS take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: I understand your point. But can you please point me to the cause and resolution for this.

Comment: I don't really think there is much you can do about it as there may sometimes be an issue with your internet provider, but sometimes also within the `yumzing network`. From your application's point of view, I guess you could provide a nice error message and a retry mechanism for the user.